# Why does Celery have different behaviors in two ways of starting the worker?

Tags: python, celery, python-module, python-importlib

I added a Celery worker into package `app`:

```
proj
├── app
│   ├── worker.py
│   └── server.py
└── db
    ├── db.sql
    ├── check_db_health.py
    └── documents.md
```

I can run the worker in both ways:

```sh
#1st way
user@host:~/proj
$ celery worker -A app.worker

#2nd way
user@host:~/proj
$ python -m app.worker
```

But there are different behavior between them.

- The second one doesn't have customizable-arguments for the worker so I don't want to use it. But it runs PERFECTLY! no error found.
- The first one boots well also but it usually meet the module import error when the task is triggered due to the real code of project having dynamic modules importing chain.

**server.py**

```py
from app.worker import enqueue

def sum(a, b):
  return a+b

enqueue(sum, a, b)
```

**worker.py**

```py
def enqueue(callback, *args, **kwargs):
    module_path = inspect.getfile(callback)
    module_name = inspect.getmodule(callback).__name__
    func_name   = callback.__name__
    no_delay = kwargs.pop('no_delay', False)
    return do_legacy_task.apply_async(args=args, kwargs=dict(kwargs, **{
        "module_name": module_name,
        "module_path": module_path,
        "func_name": func_name
    }))
    return None


@task(bind=True, name="app.worker.do_callback_task")
do_legacy_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    clean_kwargs = copy.deepcopy(kwargs)
    module_path  = clean_kwargs.pop('module_path')
    module_name  = clean_kwargs.pop('module_name')
    func_name    = clean_kwargs.pop('func_name')

    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
    if spec is None:
        print("can't find the module %s in file %s" % (module_name, module_path,))
    else:
        module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)
        sys.modules[module_name] = module

        callback = getattr(module, func_name)
        return callback(*args, **clean_kwargs)
    return None
```

The server & worker dynamic import technique is based on this [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-programmatically)

**error**

```
File "/Users/johndoe/proj/app/server.py", line 16, in <module>
    from db.check_db_health import CodeDiagnostic
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'
```

Why do two-ways-above have different behavior in import other modules?
How to fix the error above?

**UPDATE**
I found that I can skip this error by passing an extra argument for Celery:

```sh
user@host:~/proj
$ celery worker -A app.worker --include db.check_db_health
```

It would be great if there is a way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the importing module mechanism of Celery. But when you want to interact a worker with different packages in a project; you should add these packages into `celeryconfig.py`:

**celeryconfig.py**

```py
include = [
    'db. check_db_health', # a module
    'tests'                # or a package with a ready __init__.py 
]
```

Celery uses config above to load listed modules into the process.